# Solve equation with modulo for $b$?

Tags: number-theory, discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic

I have the equation $(ax + b) \mod p = q$. I wish to solve this for $b$. I was thinking that since $(ax + b) \mod p = (ax + b) - \lfloor \frac{(ax + b)}{p} \rfloor p$, it would make sense if you could rewrite the equation as $b = q - ax + \lfloor \frac{(ax + b)}{p} \rfloor p$. However, I found out that the correct result is that $b = (q - ax) \mod p$.

My question is: Can anyone explain why the $\mod p$ is simply kept but moved to the other side of the expression? In other words, explain how the $b = (q - ax) \mod p$ is derived :)

Comment: Write $c\equiv d\bmod p$ as equation $c=d$ in the ring $\Bbb Z/p$. Then of course, $ax+b=q$ is the same as $b=q-ax$, because we have have a ring, right?

Comment: @DietrichBurde Thanks for the input but I am not strong in ring theory - what does it mean to write $a = b$ in $\mathbb{Z} \backslash p$?

Comment: @DietrichBurde Indeed, it makes sense if you simply consider it equality - but what I don't understand is how you can just remove the $\mod p$? Also, what rule are you referring to?

Comment: Take $p=2$. Then we consider two integers as equal if they have the same parity. So, for example $2\equiv 0\bmod 2$ simply means $2=0$ in $\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z$. Or $3=1$. So we can convert modulo equivalences to equations in the "quotient ring". The rule I refer to is the very definition of $a\equiv b\bmod p$. Namely that $p$ divides $b-a$.

Comment: In mathematics, "congruent (mod $p$)" is a relation between two quantities (that could be true or false depending on the quantities). This is different from the way that "(mod $p$)" is treated in computer science, say, where it is a function that takes an input and outputs a number. So we would write $ax+b\equiv q\pmod p$ as a relation between the two quantities $ax+b$ and $q$. And it turns out to be true that we can do normal algebraic steps with $\equiv$ (which is why we use that notation!), so that $ax+b\equiv q\pmod p$ becomes $b\equiv q-ax\pmod p$. (Warning: division is more complicated.)

Comment: @GregMartin Perfect, I fully understand now! Appreciated

Comment: @DietrichBurde Your last comment made me get the idea, thanks :)